# After or Before text alignment element can't dragging properly element in square border

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I created dragging text functionality. When I apply text-alignment on the element, it  can't drag *properly*. I am applying alignment using radio           buttons (left,center,right)

I can't drag elements *properly* after or before alignment.

```
 <head>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style>
     #drg {
        width:300px;
        height:300px;
        border:2px solid blue;
     }
  </style>
  <script>
   $(function() {
    //left alignment
    $("input:radio[id=t1]").click(function(){
      $( "#draggable3" ).css('text-align','left');
    });

    //center alignment
    $("input:radio[id=t2]").click(function(){
      $( "#draggable3" ).css('text-align','center');
    });
    //right alignment
    $("input:radio[id=t3]").click(function(){ 
      $( "#draggable3" ).css('text-align','right');  
    });

    $( "#draggable3" ).draggable({
     cursor: 'move',        // sets the cursor apperance
     containment: '#drg',
     start: function( event, ui ) {
       $( 'input:radio[name=t1]' ).prop( "checked", false );
       $( "#draggable3" ).css('text-align','justify');
     }
    });
   });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    left <input type="radio" name="t1" id="t1" />
    center<input type="radio" name="t1"id="t2"  />
    right<input type="radio" name="t1"id="t3"  />

    <div id="drg">
        <h5 id="draggable3" > test</h5> 
    </div>
 </body>
```

[image: x]

Comment: do you mean that if you drag the element after center or right alignment, it's again going to right element huh?

Comment: tell me the exact problem what do you want to do?

Comment: i cant dragging element freely.. In sort cant drag element..

Comment: i cant dragging element..

Comment: so you want to drag the element all around your container right?

Comment: and also after right,left or center alignment cant dragging element properly.. please check code in online editor(jsbin.com)

Comment: kk i understand wait i post

Comment: Yes exactly i want to drag element after or before alignment(right,left,center) around container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
<div id="drg" style="height:200px;width:200px;border:solid 1px blue;">
            <h5 id="draggable3" style="position:absolute" > test</h5> </div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var text = "left", pos=0;
        $("input:radio[id=t1]").click(function () {
            $("#draggable3").css('position', 'initial');
            $("#draggable3").css('text-align', 'left');
            text = "left";
            pos = 0;
        });

        // center aligment
        $("input:radio[id=t2]").click(function () {
            $("#draggable3").css('position', 'initial');
            $("#draggable3").css('text-align', 'center');
            text = "center";
            pos = 0;
        });
        //right alligment
        $("input:radio[id=t3]").click(function () {
            $("#draggable3").css('position', 'initial');
            $("#draggable3").css('text-align', 'right');
            text = "right";
            pos = 0;
        });
        $("#draggable3").mousedown(function (e) {
            if (text == "left" && pos == 0) {
                $("#draggable3").css('position', 'absolute');
                $("#draggable3").css('left', '0px');
                $("#draggable3").css('top', '0px');
            }
            if (text == "right" && pos == 0) {
                $("#draggable3").css('position', 'absolute');
                $("#draggable3").css('left', ($("#drg").width() - $(this).width()) + "px");
                $("#draggable3").css('top', '0px');
            }
            if (text == "center" && pos == 0) {
                $("#draggable3").css('position', 'absolute');
                $("#draggable3").css('left', ($("#drg").width() / 2 - $(this).width() / 2) + "px");
                $("#draggable3").css('top', '0px');
            }
        });
        $("#draggable3").draggable({
            cursor: 'move',        // sets the cursor apperance
            containment: '#drg',
            create: function (event, ui) {
            },
            beforeStart: function (event, ui) {
            },
            start: function (event, ui) {
                $('input:radio[name=t1]').prop("checked", false);
                //$("#draggable3").css('text-align', 'justify');
            },
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                $("#draggable3").css('text-align', text);
                pos = 1;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

rewrite the mousedown() like this

```
        $("#draggable3").mousedown(function (e) {
            if (text == "left" && pos == 0) {
                $("#draggable3").css('position', 'absolute');
                $("#draggable3").css('left', '10px');
            }
            if (text == "right" && pos == 0) {
                $("#draggable3").css('position', 'absolute');
                $("#draggable3").css('left', ($("#drg").width() - $(this).width()+10) + "px");
            }
            if (text == "center" && pos == 0) {
                $("#draggable3").css('position', 'absolute');
                $("#draggable3").css('left', ($("#drg").width() / 2 - $(this).width() / 2+10) + "px");
            }
        });
```

all the best. Hope it will work..

Comment: if you still have any problem comment it, if it worked, accept it.

Comment: SUPPOSE YOU ELEMENT DRAGGING ON CENTER,THEN CLICK ON ELEMENT IT WILL AUTOMATICALLY SET ON LEFT ALIGNMENT, PLZ SOLVE THIS ISSUE

Comment: no its working fine. i think you did something wrong try again.

Comment: give me exact problem.

Comment: REFRESH PAGE AND DRAG ELEMENT ON CENTER AND CLICK ON ELEMENT. WHEN YOU CLICK ON ELEMENT POSITION IS CHANGE.THIS IS ISSUE

Comment: NOW ONE LITTLE PROBLEM.PROBLEM IS THAT WHEN YOU DRAG ELEMENT IN CENTER THEN YOU CLICK THAT TIME POSITION IS CHANGE... THEN SECOND TIME WORK FINE. BUT FIRST TIME CLICK PISITION IS CHANGE. SORRY FOR TROUBLING

Comment: kkk juzz try this, this will help.. i edit the above answer and append it below of above answer look at that.

Answer (score 0):

rewrite mousedown() like this which little one problem is solve

```
$("#draggable3").mousedown(function (e) {

        if (text == "left" && pos == 0) {
            $("#draggable3").css('position', 'absolute');
            $("#draggable3").css('left', '10px');
            $("#draggable3").css('top', '5px');

        }
        if (text == "right" && pos == 0) {
            $("#draggable3").css('position', 'absolute');
            $("#draggable3").css('left', ($("#drg").width() - $(this).width()) + "px");
            $("#draggable3").css('top', $("#drg").position().top);
        }
        if (text == "center" && pos == 0) {
        alert(text);
            $("#draggable3").css('position', 'absolute');
            $("#draggable3").css('left', ($("#drg").width() / 2 - $(this).width() / 2) + "px");
            $("#draggable3").css('top',$("#drg").position().top);
        }
    });
```